# Three.js r71: Point Cloud convert to Mesh and last to STL

Tags: javascript, stl, three.js

I have a cloud with 303 360 particles which are created with Vector3 with xyz position, how can I pass that cloud of particles / points to be a closed-faced object, and then be exported to STL correctly?

I am using `three.min.js` with `THREE.PointCloud(particles, material)`

http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Objects/PointCloud

Part of my code that I use is:

```
material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( { 
    attributes: attributes,
    uniforms: uniforms,
    vertexShader: shaderCache.vertex,
    fragmentShader: shaderCache.fragment,
    depthWrite: true
});

particles = new THREE.Geometry();

for (y = 0; 0 <= h ? y < h : y > h; 0 <= h ? y++ : y--) {
    for (x = 0; 0 <= w ? x < w : x > w; 0 <= w ? x++ : x--) {
        xc = (x - (w / 2)) * useEvery * 1;
        yc = ((h / 2) - y) * useEvery * 1;
        particle = v(xc, yc, 0);
        particle.usualY = yc;
        particles.vertices.push(particle);
    }
}

particleSystem = new THREE.PointCloud( particles, material );
scene.add(particleSystem);
```

Comment: you would have to use external software to convert a pointcloud to a closed surface object. MeshLab software can do that.

Comment: I have actually done so, but I do it myself curiosity by code, any ideas?

Comment: so if you have done it, I am not quite sure I understand your question.

Comment: Yeah, I do not want to take any alternative software from my code. I need to create what makes MeshLab exclusively within WebGL, or write it in Python or C ++.